# How to compare ordered datasets with the dataset before?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select * from events order by Source, DateReceived
```

This gives me something like this:

[image]

I would like to get the results which i marked blue -> When there are two or more equal ErrorNr-Entries behind each other FROM THE SAME SOURCE.

So I have to compare every row with the row before. How can I achieve that?

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the row number over partition by option on your table:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Source ORDER BY datereceived) 
    AS Row,
* FROM events
```

Either you can run a (max) having > 1 option on the result set's row number. Or if you need the details, apply the same query deducting the row nuber with 1.
Then you can make a join on the source and the row numbers and if the error nr is the same then you have a hit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the partition by as below.

```
select * from(select 
*,row_number()over(partition by source,errornr order by Source, DateReceived) r
from
[yourtable])t
where r>1
```

You can specify your column names in the outer select.